# what does view.center means in ios?

Tags: ios

just as the question title,what does view.center means,
on my first look I think it's the center coordinate,but my practice proved it's not.
for example,I try to use`subView.center = parentView.center`
to set subView locates in center of parentView,but not succeed,
so who can tell me the meaning of `view.center`,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `centre` is a `CGPoint` expressed in terms of the superview's coordinate system and it determines the position of the exact center point of the view.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/):

> The center property can be used to adjust the position of the view
>   without changing its size. The bounds defines the internal dimensions
>   of the view as it sees them and is used almost exclusively in custom
>   drawing code.

Answer (score 2):

The `subView.center = parentView.center` will not work because `center` of the superview is using its superview coordinates. See [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center) for more information.

Comment: thanks,from the doc I know why my code doesn't works,but a question still confuses me.
when my app runs on iphone6,I find the viewController.view.center = (300,300),why is (300,300)?

Comment: It doesn't work because a view and its superview have different superviews (obviously). It would work for two views that have the same superview.